# Does Photos make its own copy of the photos that are imported to it?

Tags: macos, photos.app

I have just migrated to OS X and have a lot of photos to import from my previous machine. The photos are already organised in a directory structure that I'm very happy with (i.e. 2016-05-04 Glasgow Trip).

**Is Photos making a copy of the photos in my existing directories, or is it copying them elsewhere?**

I'm thinking of disk space use (are the photos stored twice?), and depending on that answer, will the originals and the Photos versions get out of sync?

Comment: It depends. You set that in the settings somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to tell Photos to make a copy when importing or not.  In `Photos --> Preferences` check `Copy items to the photo library`.

Photos' default behavior is *not* to include original images in imports. It keeps links to them, so you can use **Photos** to edit or catalog them but still keep them where they are.

It reduce the size of **Photos**' library but if your goal is to clean up folders and disks with lots of photos on them, it can get confusing. To put everything actually in your Photos library, make sure to modify Photos' preferences to copy imported files to your Photos library. There's another important reason to do this if you plan to share those imported images on other devices: Only items copied to Photos' library will be uploaded to iCloud Photo Library. [link](http://www.imore.com/how-import-images-and-folders-photos-os-x)

[image]